# Failed to connect to SMTP server

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, mail-server

```
//aspx.cs file    
protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailHelper.SendMailMessage("naresh7590@gmail.com", "cheekucheekuarena@gmail.com", "", "", "Sample Subject", "Sample body of text for mail message");
}


//MailHelper.cs
 using System.Net.Mail;

public class MailHelper
{
    public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc, string cc, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));


        if ((bcc != null) && (bcc != string.Empty))
        {
            mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
        }

        if ((cc != null) && (cc != string.Empty))
        {
            mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
        }      

        mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mMailMessage.Body = body;

        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);//Error here
    }
}
```

I'm getting error at `mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage)`.

Could you help me with it?

Comment: What is the error message? Is it the same one you removed from the title?

Comment: Now I'm getting the error mentioned in the present title at the mentioned line.

Comment: Do you actually have an SMTP server running on the same machine as your code is running on?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the from address is a gmail account i'm assuming you are trying to send an email through GMAIL, if not there is a problem with your SMTP server in the local machine.
I hope this helps:

```
    public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc, string cc, string subject, string body)
    {
        //Creating Mail Message
        var mMailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
            mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(bcc);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
            mMailMessage.CC.Add(cc);
        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        //Sending Mail Message through GMAIL
        var mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "GMAIL Password");
        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned these settings in web.config file.

Comment: sorry, what settings? do you mean, the server address, port and account name and password?

Answer (score -1):

Your title says it all. The server does only allow TLS connections.
All explained here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2487

Comment: Not able to understand It's very big article.Can you be precise in what is wrong in my code.